# What is causing an Identifier Error in C from Header File?

Tags: c, header-files

I am new to C and seem to have a misunderstanding of how header files seem to work.
For simplicities sake, I have three files: tree.h, lib.c, and main.c

In tree.h, I have

```
struct Node
{
    void* item;
    Node** nodes;
};

struct Tree
{
    Node* tree_root;
    int depth, item_size;
};

void initializeTree(Tree*, int);
```

It is my understanding that this initializeTree method is a function "signature', and that the compiler then will know a little about the function whenever I call it in lib.c, or any other .c file that includes the header file tree.h.
However, in lib.c I have the error 'identifier Tree is undefined'.

```
#include <tree.h>

void initializeTree(Tree* tree, int item_size)
```

What is causing this error? Would the compiler not be able to 'see' the Tree struct from the included header file?

Comment: `Tree* tree` -> `struct Tree* tree`. The `struct` keyword is part of the type name. Alternatively you can use `typedef` to make an alias that doesn't have `struct`.

Comment: and... `Node** nodes;` --> `struct Node** nodes;`

Answer (score 5):

There is no `Tree`, there is only a `struct Tree`<sup>(a)</sup>. While C++ allows the short form, C does not.

In C++, a `struct` is a slight variation on a `class` and they are both types accessible *without* the `struct/class` prefix. However, the rules in C are different because, despite the similarities and history of the two languages, they are now *very* different beasts.

So, in C, you either have to use the *full* type name:

```c
struct Tree { blah blah };
void initializeTree(struct Tree *, int);
```

or `typedef` it thus:

```c
typedef struct sTree { blah blah } Tree; // struct sTree =~ Tree
void initializeTree(Tree *, int);
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You have the *same* issue with `Node`, by the way.

Comment: C++ is a different language. The keyword `struct` declares a class, which is a data type, but with an other default accessibility than `class`. That's why you don't need to `typedef` in C++.